# Rigid Type Variable error in Haskell Type Class

Tags: haskell

As a new Haskeller, I don't get my mind around all aspects, so hopefully someone can help: In my Haskell code, I have the following Type Class declaration:

```hs
class Solution a where
  solve :: (Show b) => a -> b
```

The Solution class defines one `solve` function that takes an implementation of Solution
and provides a generic type that implements Show.

I implement this class in my own algebraic type, requiring a String as return value: `String` clearly
implements `Show`:

```hs
data SpecificSolution = SpecificSolution

instance Solution SpecificSolution where
  solve :: SpecificSolution -> String
  solve p = "Result"
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘String’
  Expected: SpecificSolution -> b
    Actual: SpecificSolution -> String
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      solve :: forall b. Show b => SpecificSolution -> b
```

I don't understand why? The generic type `b` defined in the Type Class Solution is
implemented as String in SpecificSolution, which satisfies `Show b`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've attempted to do was this: (not actual valid Haskell)

```
class Solution a where
  solve :: a -> (∃ b . Show b => b)
```

Read this as "the result of the function is a value of some type chosen by its implementation; all we can say is that it will be a member of the `Show` class". Then, instantiating this with `SpecificSolution -> String` would indeed be valid.

The signature you wrote,

```
 solve :: (Show b) => a -> b
```

expresses however something very different; its explicit form is

```
 solve :: ∀ b . (Show b) => a -> b
```

That means whoever *calls* `solve` gets to choose what type `b` should be, and `solve` somehow must be able to provide it; the only assumption it can made about it is that it should be in the `Show` class. So an instantiation of `solve` can't just decide to make the `result` a `String` – after all I could choose to call it, demanding the result be `Int`, which would be perfectly within my right seeing as `Int` does have a `Show` instance.

---

There really is no point in making this method polymorphic in the result. Even if you could give it the existential type above – the only thing anybody else could then do with the result is to `show` it. So why not just `show` it right away and make the `String` the result?

```
class Solution a where
  solve :: a -> String
```

Comment: Yes, this was my approach, in the end. My intention was that "solve" should be able to return anything, as long as it is convertible to a String: The Solution class is part of a larger app that just invokes solve on any number of Solution instances, and prints the result (which therefore need to be string-convertible). The solve function should not be forced to return a String. But if this is the way, so be it :-)

Comment: There are examples where it makes sense to allow returning different types, this is not one of them. When you want different types, then it is typically one fixed type for each instance; this can be done with an [associated type synonym family](https://serokell.io/blog/type-families-haskell#associated-types).